# I need to iterate table using css selectors

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

[image][image: screenshot of the page]

I am trying to automate a page using selenium webdriver. The page contains a table which has the following xpath.

Find below a sample xpath validation which works fine.
I am iterating it through div as rows are considered as div under which there will be a table which has all the rows mentioned.

```
table = common.getObjectByXpath("html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div");
rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("div"));

    for(int i=1;i<=rows.size();i++){
        if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div["+i+"]/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/span").getText().equals("endnode 11.1"))){
            System.out.println(" print Something");
        }
    }
```

It works fine with xpath. But I want to do it with css selector. I am attaching the sample format of the table.
In the below figure, each div is considered as a row and under which you will see a table which has entries for columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xpath you are using is a very fragile one since it starts right from the `html` element and heavily depends on the HTML structure of the page. Needless to say - it is huge and is not quite readable and easily understandable.

Instead *rely on the element attributes - classes or ids*. For example:

```
div#dojox_grid__View_11 div.dojoxGridContent div.dojoxGridRow
```

Comment: "dojox_grid__View_11" will keep on changing and is there a way we could have a pattern match for this string alone?

Comment: @Leo yup, for example a starts-with version: `div[id^=dojox_grid__View_]`

Comment: Thanks. It woks fine. But I am stuck with another issue. Looks like if the table grows beyond 75 rows, it creates a new div  with role="presentation" is created. This gets created only when i scroll beyond 75 rows. Since a new one is created only when you scroll I am not sure how to handle it.  Attached the screenshot for both. First screenshot is after scrolling and second screenshot is before

Comment: @Leo could you please elaborate the latest problem into a separate question describing your desired result? I think it makes sense since it looks like a separate new problem. Throw me a link here also. Thank you!

Comment: Sure. I will post it and send you the link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28892357/how-to-handle-div-that-is-created-dynamically-in-a-table